# How can I execute cmd command from winform app and close app?

Tags: c#, cmd, uninstallation

Is there a way to parse cmd command from winform c# application and close app while this command is going to execute? ( I want to parse 2 commands: first is uninstall current application and second install msi file)

I tried to execute unistall command using Process.Start but it didnt work for me.

```
string unistall = "/x [ProductCode] /quiet";            
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = unistall;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

I expect that the app will send two commands in to the command line and close itself, without waiting for the commands to finish.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "parse"? Your question more implies that you want to "execute" cmd commands, rather then "parse" them?!?

Comment: Yes, I meant execute

Comment: I only have limited knowledge about the topic, but I doubt it will work out as you want. Since Windows itself has a limitation that it can only run 1 msi package at a given time, so it will have to wait for the first msi (uninstall) to finish before it can issue the second msi (install). What you are probably seeing is the wait between issuing those two commands, if you only run the first msi your given code should not wait till the uninstall is done. (so I assume)